# Why do I get a white/blank page on new React app?

Tags: reactjs

**This is solved - Here's what it was:**
*I had confused `create-react-app` with `start-react-app`, which still created an app, which caused the confusion.*

I've recently created a new react app, but it gives me a white/blank page. I do see the default favicon and the title of the app.

I've done the basics steps to create the app:
`npx start-react-app frontend`
`cd frontend`
`npm start`

It gives me following error:

```
imacs-imac:frontend imac$ npm start

> frontend@0.1.0 start /Users/imac/Desktop/project/frontend
> node scripts/start.js

Project is running at http://localhost:9000/
webpack output is served from /
Content not from webpack is served from /Users/imac/Desktop/project/frontend/public
webpack: wait until bundle finished: /
(node:2016) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'cat' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:2016) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'cd' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2016) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'chmod' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2016) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'cp' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2016) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'dirs' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2016) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'pushd' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2016) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'popd' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2016) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'echo' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2016) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'tempdir' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2016) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'pwd' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2016) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'exec' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2016) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'ls' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2016) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'find' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2016) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'grep' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2016) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'head' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2016) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'ln' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2016) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'mkdir' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2016) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'rm' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2016) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'mv' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2016) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'sed' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2016) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'set' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2016) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'sort' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2016) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'tail' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2016) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'test' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2016) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'to' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2016) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'toEnd' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2016) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'touch' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2016) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'uniq' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2016) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'which' of module exports inside circular dependency
Hash: 0f0125be68c02e27c57615ee1d2b5825
Version: webpack 2.7.0
Time: 20771ms
                                 Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
static/js/main.0f0125be68c02e27c57615ee1d2b5825.js    2.91 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
                            index.html  329 bytes          [emitted]         
chunk    {0} static/js/main.0f0125be68c02e27c57615ee1d2b5825.js (main) 1.07 MB [entry] [rendered]
   [84] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 77 bytes {0} [built]
   [85] ./src/index.js 665 bytes {0} [built]
   [86] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9000 7.93 kB {0} [built]
   [87] (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js 1.57 kB {0} [built]
   [90] ./src/App.js 1.97 kB {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
  [111] ./~/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js 8.86 kB {0} [built]
  [118] ./~/react-dom/index.js 59 bytes {0} [built]
  [204] ./~/react/react.js 56 bytes {0} [built]
  [205] ./~/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {0} [built]
  [208] ./src/index.css 996 bytes {0} [built]
  [209] ./~/url/url.js 23.3 kB {0} [built]
  [211] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.67 kB {0} [built]
  [212] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.08 kB {0} [built]
  [215] (webpack)/hot nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 160 bytes {0} [built]
  [217] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9000 webpack/hot/dev-server ./index.js 52 bytes {0} [built]
     + 203 hidden modules

ERROR in ./src/App.js
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at EventEmitter.module.exports.api.report (/Users/imac/Desktop/project/frontend/node_modules/eslint/lib/eslint.js:991:31)
    at RuleContext.report (/Users/imac/Desktop/project/frontend/node_modules/eslint/lib/rule-context.js:130:25)
    at report (/Users/imac/Desktop/project/frontend/node_modules/eslint-plugin-react/lib/rules/jsx-indent.js:132:15)
    at /Users/imac/Desktop/project/frontend/node_modules/eslint-plugin-react/lib/rules/jsx-indent.js:311:11
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at checkLiteralNodeIndent (/Users/imac/Desktop/project/frontend/node_modules/eslint-plugin-react/lib/rules/jsx-indent.js:310:28)
    at EventEmitter.handleLiteral (/Users/imac/Desktop/project/frontend/node_modules/eslint-plugin-react/lib/rules/jsx-indent.js:374:7)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:412:35)
    at NodeEventGenerator.applySelector (/Users/imac/Desktop/project/frontend/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/node-event-generator.js:265:26)
    at NodeEventGenerator.applySelectors (/Users/imac/Desktop/project/frontend/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/node-event-generator.js:294:22)
    at NodeEventGenerator.enterNode (/Users/imac/Desktop/project/frontend/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/node-event-generator.js:308:14)
    at CodePathAnalyzer.enterNode (/Users/imac/Desktop/project/frontend/node_modules/eslint/lib/code-path-analysis/code-path-analyzer.js:602:23)
    at CommentEventGenerator.enterNode (/Users/imac/Desktop/project/frontend/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/comment-event-generator.js:98:23)
    at Traverser.enter (/Users/imac/Desktop/project/frontend/node_modules/eslint/lib/eslint.js:929:36)
    at Traverser.__execute (/Users/imac/Desktop/project/frontend/node_modules/estraverse/estraverse.js:330:31)
    at Traverser.traverse (/Users/imac/Desktop/project/frontend/node_modules/estraverse/estraverse.js:434:28)
 @ ./src/index.js 13:11-27
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9000 webpack/hot/dev-server ./index.js
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
    chunk    {0} index.html 547 kB [entry] [rendered]
        [0] ./~/lodash/lodash.js 544 kB {0} [built]
        [1] ./~/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./public/index.html 1.52 kB {0} [built]
        [2] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
        [3] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {0} [built]
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

## Additional Code/Info

**project/frontend**

```
node_modules
public
scripts
src
.eslintrc.json
.gitignore
package-lock.json
package.json
readme.md
webpack.config.js
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
'use strict';
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

/**
 * webpack.config.js 可以 export 一个 object，或者是一个 env 为参数的 function
 */
module.exports = function (env) {
    /**
     * 判断是否是生产环境。 当命令行运行 `webpack --env.production` 时， env.production 的值为 true
     * https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-a-function-to-use-env
     */
    const isProduction = env && env.production === true;

    return {
        // 设定代码的入口，入口可以是一个或者多个，即可以传入一个 array
        // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/
        context: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
        entry: './index.js',

        // 打包好的代码存放的位置和文件名
        // 这里的 [name].[hash].js 的格式意味着会自动生成一个带 hash 的文件名
        // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
            filename: 'static/js/[name].[hash].js'
        },

        module: {
            /**
             *  loader 相当于一个预处理器。
             *  因为正常来说，webpack 只能解析 js，因此，如果过我们要引入非 js 的模块
             *  就需要一个预处理器来告诉 webpack 该如何处理这个文件，比如 css、图片等
             *  https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/
             */
            loaders: [
                /**
                 * eslint-loader
                 * 在构建之前，自动进行 eslint 检查
                 * 这里的配置设定为，如果有 error，那么就不能继续构建
                 * https://github.com/MoOx/eslint-loader
                 */
                {
                    enforce: "pre",
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                    loader: "eslint-loader",
                    options: {
                        failOnError: true,
                        fix: true
                    }
                },
                /**
                 * babel-loader
                 * 将 es6 转化为 es5
                 * https://github.com/babel/babel-loader
                 */
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    query: {
                        babelrc: false,
                        presets: [require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app')],
                    },
                },
                /**
                 * css-loader & style-loader
                 *  用来处理代码中 import './style.css' 的情况
                 *  如果是开发环境，那么作为 style 标签插入到 html 中
                 *  如果是正式环境，那么生成单独的文件，作为 link 插入的 html 中
                 *  https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader
                 *  https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader
                 */
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    loader: isProduction ?
                        ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: [
                            {
                                loader: require.resolve('css-loader')
                            },
                            {
                                loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
                                options: {
                                    plugins: () => [
                                        require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                                        autoprefixer({
                                            browsers: [
                                                '>1%',
                                                'last 4 versions',
                                                'Firefox ESR',
                                                'not ie < 9',
                                            ],
                                            flexbox: 'no-2009',
                                        }),
                                    ],
                                },
                            }
                        ] }) :
                        [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader', ]
                },
                /**
                 * json-loader
                 * https://github.com/webpack-contrib/json-loader
                 */
                {
                    test: /\.json$/,
                    loader: 'json-loader'
                },
                // "file" loader for svg
                // https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader
                {
                    test: /\.svg$/,
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    query: {
                        name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        /**
         * plugin 是 webpack 完成各种复杂功能的核心
         * 比如，这里面用的 HtmlWebpackPlugin，即可将生成的 js，生成 script 标签插入到指定的 html 里
         * 又比如，ExtractTextPlugin 可以加 css 生成 link 插入
         * https://webpack.js.org/concepts/plugins/
         */
        plugins: [
            new InterpolateHtmlPlugin({
                PUBLIC_URL: '' // 用于替换 index.html 里面的 %PUBLIC_URL%
            }),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                inject: true,
                template: '../public/index.html',
                minify: {
                    removeComments: true,
                    collapseWhitespace: true,
                    removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                    useShortDoctype: true,
                    removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                    removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                    keepClosingSlash: true,
                    minifyJS: true,
                    minifyCSS: true,
                    minifyURLs: true
                }
            }),
            new ExtractTextPlugin('static/css/[name].[hash].css'),
            new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(), // 用于热加载
            // 可以替换代码中的变量
            // https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/#use-case-service-urls
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'SERVICE_URL': isProduction ?
                    JSON.stringify("http://pro.example.com") :
                    JSON.stringify("http://dev.example.com"),
                "process.env": {
                    NODE_ENV: isProduction ?
                        JSON.stringify("production") :
                        JSON.stringify("development")
                }
            })
        ],
        /**
         * webpack 自带的开发 server，配合 webpack-dev-server 命令使用
         * https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#webpack-dev-server
         * https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
         */
        devServer:{
            hot: true,
            contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
            compress: true,
            port: 9000,
            publicPath: '/',
            // 设置代理，比如，请求 /api/abc 会代理制 http://localhost:7000/abc
            // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy
            // https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#http-proxy-middleware-options
            proxy: {
                "/api": {
                    target: "http://localhost:7000/",
                    pathRewrite: {"^/api" : ""},
                    secure: false,
                    changeOrigin: true
                }
            }
        },
        // 为压缩以后的代码提供 source map 方便调试
        // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/
        devtool: isProduction ?
            'hidden-source-map' :
            'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    };
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "frontend",
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "^15.5.4",
        "react-dom": "^15.5.4"
    },
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "^7.1.1",
        "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
        "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
        "babel-preset-react-app": "^2.2.0",
        "css-loader": "^0.28.1",
        "eslint": "^3.19.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.0.1",
        "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.0.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.0.1",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
        "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
        "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
        "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^3.0.0",
        "postcss-loader": "^2.0.5",
        "react-dev-utils": "^1.0.0",
        "style-loader": "^0.17.0",
        "webpack": "^2.5.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node scripts/start.js",
        "build": "export NODE_ENV=production && rm -rf ./build && webpack --env.production --optimize-minimize"
    }
}
```

**src/App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
    state = { loading: false };

    componentDidMount() {
        // 测试 devServer 的代理功能
        // fetch('/api/category')
        //     .then(resp => resp.json())
        //     .then(res => console.log('here here', res));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <div className="App-header">
                    <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                    <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
                </div>
                <p>{ this.state.loading.toString() }</p>
                <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Does anyone have an idea of what could cause this, and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share your code. This information is not sufficient.

Comment: Could you share your `App.js` file? Look like the error is from there.

Comment: I've just done a default set up using create-react-app with the same result. Looks like a bug in create-react-app (or at least in one of the dependencies of the app it generates which it fails to work around). The problem seems more suited for https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues than StackOverflow

Comment: And having glanced at the generated package.json and seen `"react": "^15.5.4"` (which is really old) I'd look at building my app by hand rather than using create-react-app.

Comment: You are welcome to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), instead of adding an answer directly into the body of the question. If you want to indicate that a question has an accepted answer, you can click the check/tick mark alongside the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **It should be `npx create-react-app frontend` not `npx start-react-app`**

Replace `start` by `create`:

```
npx create-react-app frontend
cd frontend
npm start
```

---

**Or are you purposely try to create a React from [that](https://www.npmjs.com/package/start-react-app)?**

That's definitely a mistake.

Comment: Wow that's great spotted! I've completely confused React commands with my Django habits. I guess the fact that some result came from it led me to look for a mistake elsewhere. Grateful for your sense of details and your time, thank you. :)

Comment: It took me a while ;)